# Can't set the title of the back bar button item of a view controller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, xcode4.5, osx-mountain-lion

I am training myself with an application that has a navigation controller, and the user can switch between two view controllers.
The root view controller class is called ViewController, and that's how I programmatically add the navigation controller in my app delegate:

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
navController= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: viewController];
self.window.rootViewController= navController;
```

This is navController:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController* navController;
```

The second view controller is called SecondViewController.I push it whenever the user clicks on the bar button item:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle: @"Second View" style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: self action: @selector(switchView:)];
```

This is the selector executed:

```
- (void) switchView : (id) sender
{
    if(!nextController)
    {
        nextController= [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName: @"SecondViewController" bundle: nil];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: nextController animated: YES];
}
```

Then in the second view controller appears automatically a button with the title "back", that switches to the first view.That's fine to me, but I would like to set the title and the style.So I'm trying to change the title:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title= @"First View";
```

But nothing to do, the title is still "back", how do I change it?

Also, ain't I following a wrong or unefficient approach, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `title` property of your `ViewController` class in `viewDidLoad`, that string will appear as the text of your back button when you push a `SecondViewController` onto the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for changing the button title. Init and add your own leftBarButtonItem and hide the stock back button.

```
UIBarButtonItem* backBtn =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"BUTTON_NAME" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(backAction)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

You're going to want to hide the original back button if you can and just make a backAction which can be something that uses the popViewcontrollerAnimated function (if you pushed the viewcontroller on to begin with).

```
- (void) backAction {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You made my day